# Angular directive does not find all elements it should

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, directive

I am working on a project where we are using angular. Most of the pages contains boostrap tooltips.

In all cases, those tooltips are shown on `<b>` elements.

This is example how it's done.

```
<b es-tooltip='show it is true / potwierdzić'>confirm</b>
```

Before it was done by directive it was written in jQuery, all attributes "title" where being found and converted into tooltips. Then, we swapped this to directive and now we have problems.

It does not work in all places. Sometimes the directive finds the text that is before the `<b>` tag.

I was thinking that maybe other tags like `<span>` or else are confusing it, but i cannot find any pattern.

This is fragment of one screen and it does not work:

```
<p class="interviewer">Hello {{avatar.name}}. This is John Smith. You have been selected for position in our company. </br> <span  class="draggable">Congratulations</span>.If you are still interested in the post, please <b es-tooltip='show it is true / potwierdzić'>confirm</b> your acceptance.</p>
```

And this works:

```
<p class="me">Of course, I do. I feel enthusiastic to receive this message. Can I receive a copy of the <b es-tooltip='proposal / oferta'>offer</b> and the benefits <span class="draggable">package</span></p>
```

When i trace 'element' in link function in directive, the good one results in

```
[b, context: b, jquery: "2.1.1", constructor: function, selector: "", toArray: function…]
```

While the bad (from example above):

```
[text, context: text, jquery: "2.1.1", constructor: function, selector: "", toArray: function…]
```

where this text is

```
".↵                If you are still interested in the post, please "
```

Maybe anyone knows, why this directive works such selectively?

EDIT:

esTooltip directive

```
angular.module('App').directive('esTooltip', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.tooltip({ trigger: "click hover", title: attrs.esTooltip });
            //console.log(element); - the logs i mentioned are from here
        },
    };
});
```

Comment: It might be because <p> tag is a bit different and it doesn't require to be closed. Did you try replacing <p> with <span>?
Also, just to make sure, the HTML is not inserted by jQuery, right?

Comment: You probably need to include the code of the directive and preferably a fiddle to get more help.

Comment: No, HTML is not inserted by jQuery.

Just checked the <p> -> <span> and besides page looks different than desired, it didn't solved the problem.

Comment: The one which isn't working contains an expression, the other one doesn't (`{{avatar.name}}`) - does this maybe have an impact? Aah, and this seams wrong as well: `</br>`.. ;)

Comment: Nope. Neither of these have impact on this. 

This is realy annoying problem. In 90% of cases it works, I can see no pattern what may be different.